# Trouble re-routing URL's in CI

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, routes

I'm having trouble re-routing variable URL segments to a test controller I setup. I want case 4 to redirect to my Test Controller.

> **Case1 (works)** go to URL
>   http://localhost/2fb/index.php/redirect/test
>
> //output "testing"
>
> **Case2 (doesn't work)** go to URL http://localhost/2fb/redirect/test
>
> //output "The requested URL /2fb/redirect/test was not found on this
>   server."
>
> **Case3 (works)** go to URL http://localhost/2fb/
>
> //output -> loads my Welcome Controller.
>
> **Case4 (doesn't work)** go to URL http://localhost/2fb/abc
>
> //output "The requested URL /2fb/redirect/test/abc was not found on this
>   server."

My routes.php file looks like this:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "welcome";
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route["2fb/(:any)"] = "redirect/test";
```

the redirect.php controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Redirect extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {    

    } 
    public function test()
    {
        echo "testing";                       
    } 

}
```

config.php :

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

.htaccess :

```
# Code Igniter Htaccess Rules
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
   # Rewrite URLs of the form 'x' to the form 'index.php/x'.
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

I believe my Apache config is correct because it's taking into account the .htaccess files presence.

Comment: I fixed it. Two things, I had the .htaccess file I was writing and modyfing at the root of 2fb instead of within the applications folder. I also had another .htaccess file in the applications folder that had `deny from all` written in it. I deleted this file and replaced it with the custom one with help from the directives in the answers below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed.

- .htaccess file was outside of the CI applications folder.
- .htaccess file had `deny from all` in it.

Answer (score 0):

maybe try another htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^$ /index.php [L]
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css|img|images|js|scripts|system|uploads|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|favicon\.png)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

also do you need:

```
$route["2fb/(:any)"] = "redirect/test";
```

can you just:

```
$route["2fb/(:any)"] = "redirect";
```

or

```
$route["2fb/(:any)"] = "redirect/$1";
```

Comment: when I rewrite the .htaccess file, `Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, admin@localhost and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.` I put it into the root of 2fb where the index.php file is.